# First Skill, just the errorHandler

Tags: javascript, json, alexa-skills-kit

I wanted to code my first Alexa Skill, but my very first intent isn´t working properly. The error handler comes in and responds with: "Sorry, ..."

I wanted to make a darts calculator and the first intent should return:

```
"Ok ${spieleranzahl} Spieler, wie viele Punkte sollen gespielt werden?"
```

in english:

```
"Ok ${numerOfPlayers} players, how many points are we going to play?"
```

This is my js Code, can somebody tell me what i´m doing wrong? (Please don´t mind the spacing issues down at the JSON)

```js
// This sample demonstrates handling intents from an Alexa skill using the Alexa Skills Kit SDK (v2).
// Please visit https://alexa.design/cookbook for additional examples on implementing slots, dialog management,
// session persistence, api calls, and more.
const Alexa = require('ask-sdk-core');

const LaunchRequestHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'LaunchRequest';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const speakOutput = 'Ok, mit wie vielen Spielern möchtest du spielen?';
        const repromtText = 'Nenne eine Spieleranzahl zwischen eins und vier.';
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            .reprompt(repromtText)
            .getResponse();
    }
};
//ErfasseSpieleranzahlHandler
const ErfasseSpieleranzahlHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'ErfasseSpieleranzahl';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const spieleranzahl = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.spieleranzahl.value;
        
        const speakOutput = `Ok ${spieleranzahl} Spieler, wie viele Punkte sollen gespielt werden?`;
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            //.reprompt(repromtText)
            .getResponse();
    }
};
const HelpIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'AMAZON.HelpIntent';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const speakOutput = 'You can say hello to me! How can I help?';

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            .reprompt(speakOutput)
            .getResponse();
    }
};
const CancelAndStopIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && (Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'AMAZON.CancelIntent'
                || Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'AMAZON.StopIntent');
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const speakOutput = 'Goodbye!';
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            .getResponse();
    }
};
const SessionEndedRequestHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'SessionEndedRequest';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        // Any cleanup logic goes here.
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder.getResponse();
    }
};

// The intent reflector is used for interaction model testing and debugging.
// It will simply repeat the intent the user said. You can create custom handlers
// for your intents by defining them above, then also adding them to the request
// handler chain below.
const IntentReflectorHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const intentName = Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope);
        const speakOutput = `You just triggered ${intentName}`;

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            //.reprompt('add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond')
            .getResponse();
    }
};

// Generic error handling to capture any syntax or routing errors. If you receive an error
// stating the request handler chain is not found, you have not implemented a handler for
// the intent being invoked or included it in the skill builder below.
const ErrorHandler = {
    canHandle() {
        return true;
    },
    handle(handlerInput, error) {
        console.log(`~~~~ Error handled: ${error.stack}`);
        const speakOutput = `Sorry, I had trouble doing what you asked. Please try again.`;

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            .reprompt(speakOutput)
            .getResponse();
    }
};

// The SkillBuilder acts as the entry point for your skill, routing all request and response
// payloads to the handlers above. Make sure any new handlers or interceptors you've
// defined are included below. The order matters - they're processed top to bottom.
exports.handler = Alexa.SkillBuilders.custom()
    .addRequestHandlers(
        LaunchRequestHandler,
        ErfasseSpieleranzahlHandler,
        HelpIntentHandler,
        CancelAndStopIntentHandler,
        SessionEndedRequestHandler,
        IntentReflectorHandler, // make sure IntentReflectorHandler is last so it doesn't override your custom intent handlers
    )
    .addErrorHandlers(
        ErrorHandler,
    )
    .lambda();
```

JSON-Input

```
{
"version": "1.0",
"session": {
    "new": false,
    "sessionId": "amzn1.echo-api.session.3a85cdaf-f0dc-457a-ad39-16b0517b0889",
    "application": {
        "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.85a2b11a-5d56-4c52-9613-44999914ce0f"
    },
    "user": {
        "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.AFNNC73ZRXQAKJKCRCEDOCVGUG6PH5MQ3JOACBXC4ATPMXG4WPB2LQEFAYHNGI2Q2LULPXXIUN6KGXBHDOMJTC75XCU5Z6OQCNZ5BNSFNUQHGD3M7B5Q52RG4JNPDMCO4UKNQJIUNZ3DLLWIED7RP7LIJ7QJA3ROR4Q7KWYP5UYOFF5OHNSWYKXOZH6MVSWSZYHGW2XPEQEVPLY"
    }
},
"context": {
    "System": {
        "application": {
            "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.85a2b11a-5d56-4c52-9613-44999914ce0f"
        },
        "user": {
            "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.AFNNC73ZRXQAKJKCRCEDOCVGUG6PH5MQ3JOACBXC4ATPMXG4WPB2LQEFAYHNGI2Q2LULPXXIUN6KGXBHDOMJTC75XCU5Z6OQCNZ5BNSFNUQHGD3M7B5Q52RG4JNPDMCO4UKNQJIUNZ3DLLWIED7RP7LIJ7QJA3ROR4Q7KWYP5UYOFF5OHNSWYKXOZH6MVSWSZYHGW2XPEQEVPLY"
        },
        "device": {
            "deviceId": "amzn1.ask.device.AHH2M6X2MORRNRLKQPH43LOAWIUADHUFRQGVEPUBHEYPSFXWJNIGJRUHRMUDT2P5UORD4IRELIIRK4A6YHC6QCMFEZ47FVYCR5Z5QLBNC5XA4Y5YU7G6OL4EQPDA43DAZ476EU47JKMBVWEW4YH5D6BAZHJCTYKURK5M75YDLUVWVEFSNEA5W",
            "supportedInterfaces": {}
        },
        "apiEndpoint": "https://api.eu.amazonalexa.com",
        "apiAccessToken": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjEifQ.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.d3uA1qasqTQdtqid78zvnRuE_dVz3z-czcr8ajjZ4-NtSNIa67Em3YMyLQ7nhld5e0dM8IvqiwwvViiS6e6kXMa9QZQYMeanAR994s4M7SwgQeA-9n8UebUsjMhNLORqx-SCJlcZL4sN2LqJsUuLQLA8m2VucVo9EveNGrqYQFuLHtYiadsE4xKQ-9x3GBy9th3rf1sEesrEDktRljZw44yafClegR8kz-Xv7Uso6x6SC0sO9I3iM1a5CJKFV8-3EJBQZ3cDVktPZQ2Erp-IhsyXA3LRJBWMWKx8FFSFM_p3ZeYdtcIq28KPYDSFThIWvTRh7KSXzWltm8RmFoR3JQ"
    },
    "Viewport": {
        "experiences": [
            {
                "arcMinuteWidth": 246,
                "arcMinuteHeight": 144,
                "canRotate": false,
                "canResize": false
            }
        ],
        "shape": "RECTANGLE",
        "pixelWidth": 1024,
        "pixelHeight": 600,
        "dpi": 160,
        "currentPixelWidth": 1024,
        "currentPixelHeight": 600,
        "touch": [
            "SINGLE"
        ],
        "video": {
            "codecs": [
                "H_264_42",
                "H_264_41"
            ]
        }
    },
    "Viewports": [
        {
            "type": "APL",
            "id": "main",
            "shape": "RECTANGLE",
            "dpi": 160,
            "presentationType": "STANDARD",
            "canRotate": false,
            "configuration": {
                "current": {
                    "video": {
                        "codecs": [
                            "H_264_42",
                            "H_264_41"
                        ]
                    },
                    "size": {
                        "type": "DISCRETE",
                        "pixelWidth": 1024,
                        "pixelHeight": 600
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
},
"request": {
    "type": "IntentRequest",
    "requestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.945d9c9a-49ff-423c-8d84-50de36f54c01",
    "timestamp": "2019-11-24T22:34:59Z",
    "locale": "de-DE",
    "intent": {
        "name": "ErfasseSpieleranzahl",
        "confirmationStatus": "NONE",
        "slots": {
            "Spieleranzahl": {
                "name": "Spieleranzahl",
                "value": "1",
                "confirmationStatus": "NONE",
                "source": "USER"
            }
        }
    },
    "dialogState": "COMPLETED"
}
}
```

JSON-Output

```
{
"body": {
    "version": "1.0",
    "response": {
        "outputSpeech": {
            "type": "SSML",
            "ssml": "<speak>Sorry, I had trouble doing what you asked. Please try again.</speak>"
        },
        "reprompt": {
            "outputSpeech": {
                "type": "SSML",
                "ssml": "<speak>Sorry, I had trouble doing what you asked. Please try again.</speak>"
            }
        },
        "shouldEndSession": false,
        "type": "_DEFAULT_RESPONSE"
    },
    "sessionAttributes": {},
    "userAgent": "ask-node/2.7.0 Node/v8.10.0"
}
}
```

Comment: You're logging out the stack trace of where it failed, have you tried looking in your cloudwatch logs for the error as it will narrow down the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're logging out the stack trace of where it failed, have you tried looking in your cloudwatch logs for the error as it will narrow down the line?

Though off hand I can see your slot is called `Spieleranzahl` but in your code when you try to access it you use `spieleranzahl` <- notice the lowercase 's'. The property name will be case sensitive so this could cause the error.

Here's the corrected handler:

```
//ErfasseSpieleranzahlHandler
const ErfasseSpieleranzahlHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'ErfasseSpieleranzahl';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const spieleranzahl = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.Spieleranzahl.value;

        const speakOutput = `Ok ${spieleranzahl} Spieler, wie viele Punkte sollen gespielt werden?`;
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            //.reprompt(repromtText)
            .getResponse();
    }
};
```